# How can I see which tab uses the GPU in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, gpu

I sometimes see that Google Chrome uses the amount of GPU on my computer:

[image]

How can I see which tab uses the GPU in Google Chrome? I use in Google Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 5):

If you right click anywhere in the `Task-Manager` and select `GPU-Memory`, you will see a column become visible, where each tabs GPU memory usage appears.

Comment: Thanks! is there any way to view the GPU utilization for each tab?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If you are using Windows 10, you can see the GPU utilization of each subprocess, by opening the Windows Task Manager, select the tap `Processes`, right click on `Name` and select `GPU`. Expand Chrome and you can see each subprocess GPU utilization, sadly I don't know of any method to display the GPU utilization of each tab, or how to identify these tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot ***always*** determine the tab depending on what's driving the GPU (unfortunately.)

However, often you can use one of two methods to find the offending tab.

Easiest method (if you're a bit lucky) :
[image: Direct PID Method]

... here you can see, in Windows Task Manager, we find the high GPU usage, [Go to Details]; then finally in Google Chrome Task Manager we find the matching PID.

Alternative method (doesn't always work) :
[image: Correlation PID Method]

... most of the time, the GPU requires a correlated effort on the part of the CPU ... in this example, we know that the GPU is working so then we narrow our search in the Google Processes until we find an CPU (or sometimes network) utilization that's high & go "look up" the tab & see if it is related, if not repeat.  I've found the tab(s) that cause me problems in usually under three tries.